# How to get names of all the elements that appear through the for loop and put them into the associative array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, associative-array

**This is my idea, but doesn't work properly. I tried with adding this [] brackets into name tag in HTML, but I don't like array I got. Sorry for bad english**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $name=$_POST['name_of_exam'];
    $volume=$_POST['volume'];
    $date=$_POST['date'];
    $attempt=$_POST['attempt'];
    $arr=array(
        array("Name of exam"=>$name, "Volume"=>$volume,"Date"=>$date,"Attempt"=>$attempt)
    );
    print_r ($arr);
    
 }
```

count is the number I enter at the beginning

```
for ($i=0; $i < $count; $i++) { ?>
          <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Name of Exame</label>   
          <input type="text" name="name_of_exame">
         </div>

         <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Volume</label>   
          <input type="range" min='0' max='10' value='0' name="volume">
         </div>

         <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Date</label>   
          <input type="date" name="date">
         </div>

         <div class="input-group">
          <label for="">Attempt</label>   
          <input type="text" name="attempt">
         </div>

        <?php 
     
        }   ?>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" id="">
```

I expect result like:

```
$arr=array(
array('Name'=>'Math','Volume'=>10,'Date'=>'1/30/2022','Attempt'=>2),
array('Name'=>'History','Volume'=>7,'Date'=>'1/17/2022','Attempt'=>1),
array('Name'=>'Geography','Volume'=>3,'Date'=>'1/10/2022','Attempt'=>4)
...
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need specific field names like `exams[0][name_of_exam]`. Use the `$i` from the loop.